# Relation between transminnion power and detection distance

Tags: ibeacon, ibeacon-android, beacon

I found this code and used it to start the transmission as a beacon

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 A0 00 A0 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x000a 0
```

If I right understood, the value `c5 00` is the transmission power which affect the detection range is that right?

What did this value mean and what is the relation between power and range? For example for a power of 5(is it Tx?) the detection rate is ... ?

Comment: Can you explain a little bit better? Those numbers... "1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6" you just typed your self or they are being given by the console? 

About the power: With a beacon you don't detect range... you just detect the power of the signal and then you can infer the distance. You can use it to decide if something got closer or not... of it's close enougth... But I can't have a precise relation of: power x range... since each antena will measure it diferently

Comment: These are the command to start transmitting as a beacon with bluez. For example A0 00 A0 00 will set the transmission rate to 10Hz.